# Getting a stack trace when an error occurs?

Tags: customization, debug

I was told to "get a stack trace" when an error occurs in my WordPress installation. How do I do this?

*This is meant to be an easy place to refer others to. Please list plugins, configuration settings, PHP modules... that can do this. Consider that the user might be on a shared host, might want to log to a file instead of the browser, ...*

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are after something like [WP PHP Console](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-php-console/).

Another good plugin would be the [Simple Error Handler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-error-handler/), while it should be regarded it is compatible only up to `3.8.11` and you may consider forking it to be compatible to latest version of Wordpress.